# PHP - get closest date from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, php-carbon

I want to get closest date from $search_date if is not same values in $array['date']. If is same value in $array['date'] I want all array.

- Format date is 'Y-m-d'.

Example 1:

```
$search_date = '2022-12-08';
$array = [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-12"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"}]
Return should be: [{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"}]
```

Example 2:

```
$search_date = '2022-12-08';
$array = [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-08"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-09"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-11"}]
Return should be: [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-08"}]
```

Example 3:

```
$search_date = '2022-12-08';
$array = [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-11"}]
Return should be: [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"}]
```

Example 4:

```
$search_date = '2022-12-08';
$array = [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-08"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-08"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-08"}]
Return should be: [{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-08"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-08"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-08"}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you coded something already?

Comment: Yes, a lot, but it's not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code calculates the distance in days between `$search` and each record. It assumes that you want to find closest distance in both future and past.

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Catalin Iamandei
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: PHP - get closest date from array
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598442/php-get-closest-date-from-array
Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, php-carbon

*/

$search = '2022-12-10';
$searchObj = new DateTime($search);

$records = json_decode('[{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"},{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-11"}]', true);

$distances = [];
foreach ($records as $index => $record) {
    $recordObj = new DateTime($record['date']);
    $daysDiff = $searchObj->diff($recordObj)->format("%r%a");
    $distances[$index] = abs($daysDiff);
}

$minimumDiff = min($distances);

$output = [];
foreach ($distances as $index => $distance) {
    if ($distance == $minimumDiff) {
        $output[] = $records[$index];
    }
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Yields:

```
[
    {
        "price": "50",
        "date": "2022-12-09"
    },
    {
        "price": "100",
        "date": "2022-12-11"
    }
]
```

If you only want to search for closest dates in the future, you need to remove the `abs()` function and then remove all negative entries in the `$distances` array before using `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a specific value in your array have you tried

```
array_search($value, $array);
```

By this you can search for a specific value in your array

---

If you want to search the lowest value

try to for looping your array and check if the array is lower than the previous index and if the for loop has ended you have the lowest date

```
$lowest_date = null;

for ($i = 0; count($i); $i++) {
    if ($array['date'] < $lowest_date) {
        $lowest_date = $array['date'];
    }
}
```

Comment: They want to get the closest date, which may not be an exact match and may not be the lowest date either.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have mentioned what todo with prior dates, eg. searching for `'2022-12-07'`, how to tread `2022-12-06` and `2022-12-08`, as the difference both is 1. You can calculate the datediff for each entry, get the min datediff and output elements with this datediff. eg :

```
<?php
$SearchDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2022-12-08');
$array      = array ('{"price":"200","date":"2022-12-12"}',
    '{"price":"50","date":"2022-12-10"}',
    '{"price":"100","date":"2022-12-10"}');
$laResult = array();
foreach($array as $jsonO) {
    $json             = json_decode($jsonO);
    $CompareDate      = new DateTimeImmutable($json->{'date'});
    $interval         = date_diff($SearchDate, $CompareDate);
    $laThis['date']   = $json->{'date'};
    $laThis['diff']   = $interval->format('%a');
    $laThis['origin'] = $jsonO;
    $laResult[]       = $laThis;
}

$min_diff = min( array_column( $laResult, 'diff') );
echo 'nearestDiff:'. $min_diff .PHP_EOL;
foreach($laResult as $laSingleResult) {
    if($laSingleResult['diff'] == $min_diff) {
        echo $laSingleResult['origin'] .PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```